# Getting null pointer exception changing tab from activity using multiple activities in single tab ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I will explain my problem. I have 4 tabs and each tab have multiple activities. Now i have created 4 tab group activities extending Activity Group to handle multiple activities. Now there is a situation that i have to go the the activity that is the child of 2nd tab group activity. and i want to change the current tab to 2. But it gives me null pointer exception at tab host.

How to change the ta and goto second activity group from 1st activity group? Please give idea. or any any example of how can i implement that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem of setting Tabhost widget to public static TabHost tabHost ; and changing the tab by calling TabActivity.tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);